# Unable to combine video with audio using FFMPEG android

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG shared library(.so) in my android app to add watermark in video, changing audio format from .wav to .mp3 and combine video with audio. I can able to run ffmpeg command successfully to add watermark for selected video, to change .wav format audio to .mp3. It is working fine. But while trying to combine audio with video, I got error **"ffmpeg: Exit program called. 1"**. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I have installed FFMPEG in my ubuntu 16.04LTS system and executed command from terminal to combine audio with video. It is working perfectly.

But when using same command from android code to combine audio with video I got Exit program called. 1 error. Below commands are used to combine audio with video.

1. ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i outputaudio.wav -c copy output.mkv
2. ffmpeg -i outputaudio.wav -i out.mp4 -vcodec copy abc.mkv
3. ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.